# Writing async monotouch code

Tags: .net, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, task-parallel-library, azure-mobile-services

So I have a method that must execute three tasks. 
The first task must be completed before the other two, which can be executed in parallel.
This is what I have right now (modified for simplicity)

```
void facebookButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            View.Add (loadingOverlay);
            AppDelegate.MobileService = new MobileServiceClient ("myserverUrl", "myApiKey");
            var users= AppDelegate.MobileService.GetTable<User> ();
            var identities= AppDelegate.MobileService
                .GetTable ("Identities");
            AppDelegate.MobileService
                .LoginAsync (this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook)
                    .ContinueWith (t => {
                if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) {
                            AppDelegate.mobileServiceUser = t.Result;
                            var task1 = users.InsertAsync(new User{BirthDate = DateTime.Now});
                            var task2 = identities.ReadAsync("");
                            Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new Task[]{task1,task2},_=>{
                                if(task1.Status==TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task2.Status== TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                                {
                                    var token = task2.Result
                                        .GetArray()[0]
                                        .GetObject ()
                                        .GetNamedObject ("identities")
                                        .GetNamedObject ("facebook")
                                        .GetNamedString ("accessToken");    

                                SaveAuthorization (token);
                                NavigationController.PushViewController (new TabBarController (), false);
                                }
                            });             
                        }});
        }
```

The problem is (other than Im a newb at async code) that when it tries to execute "PushViewController" I get:

> UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are
>   calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread

How can I refactor/modify this code to fix it?
please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at InvokeOnMainThread or BeginInvokeOnMainThread

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Threading#Developing_Responsive_Applications

```cs
NavigationController.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (delegate { 
    NavigationController.PushViewController (new TabBarController (), false);
});
```

Comment: I did not check this, I do not have a compiler in front of me.  Let me know if it has errors.

Answer (score 16):

I call InvokeOnMainThread and use an anonymous function in my asynchronous methods.

```cs
InvokeOnMainThread(() => {  
    NavigationController.PushViewController (new TabBarController(), false);
});
```

If for some reason you are in a static class (like I was), you can do this

```cs
new NSObject().InvokeOnMainThread(() => {   
    NavigationController.PushViewController (new TabBarController(), false);
});
```

Comment: In case any other confused new Xamarin devs come across this, this answer is basically the same answer as above, only using a lambda expression instead of a delegate method, while also including the static class case handling.